# How to modify CRUD permission on an object programmatically?

Tags: permissions, crud

I want to modify CRUD permissions for a custom object inside my Visualforce page controller (accessible only by administrators) in order to hide/show this object to other users when clicking on a button.

My goal is to avoid losing time doing it manually especially if there are lots of profiles.

Is there an easy way to do this ?

I know how to check for permissions, but not how to modify them :

```
if (Schema.sObjectType.MyObject.isAccessible())
{

}
```

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't directly answer your question but your best solution would be to use Permission sets (see [here](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=perm_sets_overview.htm)) and use the standard Salesforce admin UI to assign to the correct users. If you create a permission set for each of the CRUD permissions would may want to assign then the admin will just need to assign as and when necessary.

Comment: Thanks Richard, it could be a solution, but the problem is that permission sets cannot be assigned to profiles, but to users.

Comment: You can create you VF page to look for users that match the profile you want to administer and apply the permission set in Apex. See https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_permissionsetassignment.htm for the PermissionSetAssignment object